# Async method in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I have to call some async methods in the Application_PostAcquireRequestState method of my Global.asax (these methods comes from a library and there's no equivalent sync method for these operations). I want to be sure this async code complete before continuing with my page process because some security parameters are set with the result of that async call.

What will be the proper way to make this work without creating deadlocks ?

Thanks

Comment: will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just call the `Result` property of the `Task` that the `*Async()` methods return, for example.

```
var result = BarAsync().Result;
```

If the methods return `Task` rather than `Task<T>`, use `Wait()`:

```
BarAsync().Wait();
```

Comment: It works but I'm a bit confused : why does it works in global.asax and not in the code behind of a page (deadlock) ?

Comment: @mberube.Net This question may enlighten you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304691/why-are-iis-threads-so-precious-as-compared-to-regular-clr-threads

Comment: FYI: I should mention that this is not working inside the constructor! it can be so buggy! Just as a fact.