# Does IIS 10 spawn multiple threads for concurrent requests? If so, on what basis does it decide whether to spawn a new thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis

In case of concurrent requests, does IIS 10 spawn new thread(s) for each or some of those requests? I created a simple .NET Web API thread number logger application that logged the 'Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId' and simulated near-concurrent requests using Postman and observed that each subsequent request ran on a different thread and same threads are re-used occasionally. Hence trying to understand the relation between IIS concurrency and thread spawning.

Comment: There's a discussion here, though I'm not sure it totally answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304691/why-are-iis-threads-so-precious-as-compared-to-regular-clr-threads

Comment: Based on your description, you already observed the typical thread pool usage, which is the core of IIS concurrency. I wonder what else you would like to learn.